# How to fix error: NameError: name ' var' is not defined

Tags: python, api

I am new to Python and am trying to use Google's Speech Recognition API, unfortunately I have been unable to fix the NameError: name 'command' is not defined when compiling. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import speech_recognition as sr, pyttsx3, datetime, wikipedia, webbrowser, time, pywhatkit;
 
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
 
def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
 
def take_cmd():
    global command
    try: 
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
 
            print('Listening..')
            listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")
 
 
            if 'atlas' in command:
                command = command.replace('atlas', '')
                command.lower
                print(command)
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return command
 
 
def run_atlas():
    command = take_cmd()
 
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
 
while True:
    run_atlas()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no global variable `command`. It's local to the `run_atlas` function. In short, never use globals. Pass arguments to functions and return values.

Answer (score 0):

You defined command in the local scale, you must define it in the global scale. If you have ever used js the local and global scales in python are like the local and global scales js.